# В чем отличие между деревом разбора и абстрактным синтаксическим деревом?

Tags: компилятор, грамматика, дерево

Сейчас изучаю книгу Ульмана "Компиляторы - принципы, технологии, инструменты". Автор ввел эти два понятия, но я не могу понять отличия.

Comment: Думаю книгу тут врядли кто читал именно эту. Скажу что задача подсветка синтаксиза гораздо проще чем разбор кода, и не требует связи всех частей кода так плотно.

Comment: _Автор ввел эти два понятия_ - не плохо было бы определения из книги привести

Comment: Есть правила которые на смысл программы не влияют. Ну например всякие лишние скобочки для группировки операндов. В ast их нет так как не нужны, в дереве разбора - они есть. То есть ast - это такое кристализованное дерево разбора, в котором осталось только важное. btw я уверен что у Ульмана это объяснено где-то, только Вы проскочили наверн

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**В процессе обработки исходного кода строится сначала дерево разбора**, а затем из него (возможно, через дополнительные этапы) строится АСД: всевозможными устранениями синонимов, избыточных элементов, незначащих конструкций (комментариев?) — всего, что не относится к определению поведения.

Это преобразование с потерей данных. Если из дерева разбора ещё бывает возможно восстановить исходный код, то из АСД уже нет.

А вот что говорит [Википедия про АСД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE):

> Абстрактное синтаксическое дерево отличается от дерева разбора тем, что в нём отсутствуют узлы и рёбра для тех синтаксических правил, которые не влияют на семантику программы. Классическим примером такого отсутствия являются группирующие скобки, так как в АСД группировка операндов явно задаётся структурой дерева.